# Which data to respond in transient state SM(AD) MSI Split Transaction Coherent Cache?

Tags: caching, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I am trying to implement a non-blocking cache which using Optimized MSI Snooping with Split-Transaction Bus - Cache Controller.

My reference book is A Primer on Memory Consistency and Cache Coherence (Daniel J. Sorin, Mark D. Hill,David A. Wood). I am trying to implement release (weak) memory ordering.

In some transient states, cache can give response to core as SM(AD), SM(D), SM(D)I etc.

[Here is the table of states from the same book, page 131.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Vmh.png)

My question is, which data will I response to Core?

I mean lets talk about on example. L1 data cache has an address A with S state and decimal 200 value. It gets a store A request with value 300 from LSU.

In this case, this request passes from MSI CCL(Cache Coherence Logic) and issues a GetM signal with the Core ID to invalidate other cores and to inform L2.

Because of the buffers and the bus latencies, before the same L1 data cache gets any Own-GetM signal or any data of this requests, it is possible to get another load request from LSU.

This request should hit because the value it is still Shared and cache did not realize no other cores changed it.

So here is my question, which data will cache response to core when the state is SM(AD) and another loads to A hits on MSI CCL? 200 or 300?

It seems like it should be 300, but cache did not respond to core for store on A finished and core knows that.

Thanks for your time.